# Get attributes from Lucene's TermsEnum

Tags: java, lucene

When I pass some text through StandardAnalyzer, I can get TokenStream, and, iterating by it, get various token attributes, as OffsetAtribute.

```
public static void displayTokensWithFullInfo(TokenStream stream) throws IOException {
        CharTermAttribute charAttribute = stream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
        OffsetAttribute offsetAttribute = stream.addAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class);

        stream.reset();
        while (stream.incrementToken()) {
            System.out.print(offsetAttribute.startOffset() + "->" + offsetAttribute.endOffset() + " \"");
            System.out.print(charAttribute.toString());    

        }

        stream.close();
    }
```

After saving TokenStream, to index, I'm trying to get OffsetAttribute from TermsEnum, but offset values I get are always euqual to 0.

```
IndexReader reader = new IndexSearcher(DirectoryReader.open(directory)).getIndexReader();
    Terms terms = MultiFields.getTerms(reader,"field");
    TermsEnum termsEnum = terms.iterator();
                    BytesRef  bytesRef = termsEnum.next();
                    while(bytesRef  != null){
                        AttributeSource attributeSource = termsEnum.attributes();
                        OffsetAttribute offsetAttribute = attributeSource.addAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class);

                        bytesRef = termsEnum.next();
                    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it actually possible to get this attribute from TermVector? What if I want to create my own Attribute implementation, does Lucene provide this loophole?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That `TermsEnum` iterates over all occurring terms in your corpus.
This means you get "House" once, even if it occurs in many documents.

Fetching a `TermVector` / Offset for that does not make sense, since that only works in respect to a Document that contains that Term.

You possibly want to get a TermsEnum with TermVectors for a single Document:

```
TermsEnum tEnum = reader.getTermVector(123, "field").iterator()
```

see [IndexReader.getTermVector](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#getTermVector(int,%20java.lang.String))